# Failing to get price instead i am getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying webscraping on craigslist. I want to be able to retrive product title, link and prize but  I am getting this error

```
post_price = post_listings[0].find(class_='result-price').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I have tried to remove the `.text` and the result on price is `"none"`instead of displaying the actual price.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.shortcuts import render
from requests.compat import quote_plus
from . import models



BASE_CRAIGSLIST_URL = 'https://losangeles.craigslist.org/d/services/search/bbb?query={}'


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')


def new_search(request):
    search = request.POST.get('search')
    models.Search.objects.create(search=search)
    final_url = BASE_CRAIGSLIST_URL.format(quote_plus(search))
    print(final_url)
    response = requests.get(final_url)
    data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features='html.parser')

    post_listings = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'result-row'})
    post_title = post_listings[0].find(class_='result-title').text
    post_url = post_listings[0].find('a').get('href')
    post_price = post_listings[0].find(class_='result-price').text

    print(post_title)
    print(post_url)
    print(post_price)

    #print(data)
    stuff_for_frontend = {
        'search': search,
    }
    return render(request, 'my_app/new_search.html', stuff_for
```

Comment: This means `result-price` doesn't exist. This means that it returns `None`, which is a pretty basic part of Python.

Comment: The product has price when you search for it on the craigslist page

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your base url is for services, not products for sale. Services do not have a price listed.

If you change the url to the following, then your script will search for products instead of services and should find prices.
`BASE_CRAIGSLIST_URL = 'https://losangeles.craigslist.org/search/sss?query={}'`